# Div in li is it wrong usage?

Tags: css, html, xhtml, html-lists

example;

```
<ul>
  <li>
   <div class="img1"><img src="img.jpg" /></div>
   <div class="cs1">Text text</div>
   <div class="cs2">text text</div>
   <div class="button">Next</div>  
  </li>
</ul>
```

like above code block div in li. I heard it is wrong usage. Is it true?

Comment: Do you have a source/link to why it would be wrong? Just curious.

Comment: You heard wrong. `div` elements can be nested inside `li`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both elements are block elements so nesting them is fine.  Checkout the permitted content allowed in `<li>` in the [Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/li).

Answer (score 3):

According to the W3C validator it is perfectly fine to use divisions.

you can also check your html whether it is valid or not in [w3cvalidator](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Hope this validator helps.

Answer (score 1):

The best place to check it if you are in doubt is HTML DTD. It's a bit cryptic if you look at it first time, but it's a good source.

Let's look at your example: 
http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/lists.html#edef-UL

DTD stands that in UL (or OL) you can have only LI's (one or more)

```
<!ELEMENT UL - - (LI)+                 -- unordered list -->
```

Then if you take a look on LI element:

```
<!ELEMENT LI - O (%flow;)*             -- list item -->
```

it can take any element from the 'flow' shortcut (zero or more as the '*' stands for). You can click on the %flow link to learn what are those elements.

There is many other things you could learn from it, i.e. what kind of attributes given element can have etc.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is often used by developers as easier CSS friendly dropdowns among many other uses you can probably think of.

Answer (score 0):

No it's not wrong use but it depends on what you want.
If you want a drop down menu every div must be inside a `<li>`
like the example shown below.

Eg:

```
<ul>
   <li><div class="img1"><img src="img.jpg" /></div>
   <li><div class="cs1">Text text</div>  </li>
   <li><div class="cs2">text text</div>  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The HTML syntax (any version) allows a `div` element inside an `li` element, as one can easily check from the specifications, or using a validator.

In any other sense than purely syntactic, the “wrong usage” issue is here really with the use of a bulleted list (`ul` element) with a single item in it. There is nothing formally wrong with it; it just does not seem to make any sense.